# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For my API I'm using Entity Framework Core with code first migrations. I've created some relations which are working fine. Now, I've added another relation (one to many) and suddenly I'm slapped around the ears with this error:

`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Companies' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."`

Offcourse, I must be doing something wrong but I just can't figure out *what*. I've come across more questions like this where the answer was "set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON" but that doesn't work for me since EF is handling everything.

My Company class which can belong to a Group:

```cs
public class Company
{
  // Primary key
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // The optional Id of a Group
  public int? GroupID { get; set; }

...

}
```

And the Group class:

```cs
public class Group
{
  // Primary key
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Name of the Group
  public string Name { get; set; }

  // List of Companies in this group
  public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

The code used for handling the POST:

```cs
// POST api/groups
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Group group)
{
  try
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      _context.Groups.Add(group);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      return CreatedAtRoute("GetGroup", new { id = group.Id }, group);
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return BadRequest($"Unable to create: {e.Message}");
  }
}
```

In my database, all columns, index and keys are created as expected and just like every other one to many relationship I've got in my API. But this specific case just seems to end up in misery...

The class I'm trying to add to the database:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code, which part is giving exception?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: You need to make sure that the EF mapping for the entity `Company` and the DB Schema for table `Companies` are aligned. If you want to use IDENTITY for insert then make sure the tables schema is set with `IDENTITY_INSERT` **and** that the mapping has been configured for Identity Insert (this last part is likely your problem). If you do not want to use it then make sure you are passing an explicit value in the property.

Comment: The error is pretty straight-forward. You're passing an id for your group when attempting to create it in the first place. The id is an auto-incremented primary key, so the id comes from the database, not you. Don't set an explicit id, and you're fine.

Comment: @ChrisPratt it sounds pretty simple, but the thing is that i'm _not_ setting an explicit id and that EF handles everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that there's no hint for EF to know if `Company` (under `Group` relationship) is being explicitly inserted or if it is supposed to use the pre-existing one from database.

Since those instanced are disconnected from `DbContext` there is no indication whether they exist or not on the database by the time EF tries to generate its SQL command.

There is no easy way here, at least there was none by the time I've played with EF Core.

You should either:

1. Change your code to only use the `ID` instead of the navigation property so you'll avoid this whenever possible, or;
2. Change your code to fetch related data (eg: fetch `Company` and attach it to `Group`) before saving desired data (eg: before saving `Group`).

So, for instance:

```cs
var companyDB = await context.Companies.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == group.Company.Id);
group.Company = companyDB;
context.Groups.Add(group);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Yes, you're making two trips to database. That's why I'd suggest using the first approach, so you can avoid this fetch and just save `Group` entity directly into DB.

That does not, however, prohibits you from sending a navigation instace of `Company` to your view. Just create some entity-related classes which will correlate to your database so you can load/save data using this entity type, and create a `Dto` object which will be your endpoint input/output whenever needed.

Binding one into another can be done by using AutoMapper, manual linq or other approaches.

Comment: Number 2 of your solution was the actual solution for this particular problem. When posting a new Group _with_ a list of Companies, `Company.GroupID` is 0, which is the explicit value mentioned in the error. Creating a new group and adding a list of companies to it solved the problem.

Comment: @AndersonMatos Would you please add an example of the first approach in this particular case?

Comment: You mean the ID-only approach? You simply add the ID field with corresponding mappings but without any navigational property.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework lost tracking for some reason and Entity Framework needs to reestablish tracking for the entities that are already existing.

You can get the state of the entity's tracking with:

```
var entityTrackingState = _context.Entry(entity).State;
```

You can force Entity Framework to do tracking on the existing entities with:

```
_context.Entry(untrackedEntity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Where

```
_context
```

is an Entity Framework DbContext.

Forcing tracking resolved my issue, but it really should be debugged where Entity Framework is losing tracking.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing some value in a column which is set as identity (auto-increment).

I think the `Group` entity which you are inserting has the companies with the value of Id which it tries to insert in company table as child record. and it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to save an entity (for ex., `Cat`) which had many-to-one relationships to existing entities (property `Owner`, pointing at `Person`). In addition to a) getting the relationship (Person) from the database before saving the entity (`Cat`), and b) adding another property (`int PersonId`) to the entity (`Cat`), I discovered what I think is the best solution: c) stick to "navigation" properties only (do not create extra `int <<Name>>Id` properties), and when referencing is needed, use `cat.Owner = dbContext.Person.Attach(new Person { Id = 123 }).Entity;`